# How to add a snap-ins deployment to a changeset

Tags: change-set

We're in the process of implementing Live Agent chat with snap-ins, and want to move our deployment from our sandbox to test. Where do we find the Span-ins deployments to add to the changeset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveAgent snap-ins are data, not metadata, so they can't be moved up in changesets.  You could try exporting the data, but it's probably easier to just recreate them in your test sandbox.

Comment: Thanks Shane, this is exactly where we got to. I'm not a big fan of the whole snap in thing TBH.